# Proper workflow for onboarding new customers via API (we're a PMD partner)

Tags: facebook-opengraph, ads

We're actively developing our PMD ads management tool. We have a number of customers who want to advertise but don't have a Facebook account of any kind. I have a two part question:

(1) Is their an API/programmatic way for us to create a proper user account for our client so the client can in turn log in to their fresh Facebook account and enter ads payment information? For example, I can imagine an open graph call like this:

`createFBUserAccount(f_name:"Joe",l_name:"Smith",email:"joesmith@gmail.com",isbusiness:"false");`

or for a person

`createFBUserAccount(business_entity_name:"ACME Corp",email:"contact@acmecorp.com",isbusiness:"true");`

(2) For users who don't want a Facebook account but still want to advertise on Facebook through us, what is the proper way to create their ads? Let's say this is a business interested in buying External Website ads (or Mobile App Install, or any number of other ad units).

Answer (score 0):

we currently don't have a way to create Ad Accounts through API. The user will have to create an account directly through https://www.facebook.com/advertising.

We also have business accounts (doc: https://www.facebook.com/help/131976240210052)

We require either a user account or business account to advertise with us.

Hope this is helpful.